# How do I extract and compare a HttpPost response String?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, http-post

I have select query in `mysql` which gives me output like `{"flag":"true"}`

In android code how can I compare this response with any string?

select.php code

```
<?php
    $host='domain.com';
    $uname='tempdata';
    $pwd='tempdata';
    $db="tempdata";

    $con = mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("connection failed");
    mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die("db selection failed");


    $r=mysql_query("select * from test where message='hello'",$con);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r))
    {
        $flag[name]="true";
    }

    print(json_encode($flag));
    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

android code in MainActivity.java

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.myweb.com/select.php");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
```

Now I want to check response with some string so that I can do further operation.

```
for example
If response comes `true` then send email else not.

for that i need to check and compare for true value , how can I do so in android code?
```

Comment: This might be time to read a tutorial and/or apply some code. In any case, the question is probably "How to I access/read a JSON response in Android?", which is far from being uncommon. (But do *check* the response, the currently posted PHP appears invalid which is another issue entirely.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you **extract the response** `String` from the `InputStream`:

```
// load your data...

InputStream is = ...;

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line + "\n");
}

if (is != null)
    is.close();

String result = sb.toString();
```

Then, you can compare the result `String` like that for example:

```
if(result.equals(...)) {
    // do something
}
```